# Retrieving image from mongoid gridFS using carrierwave gem not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, gridfs

In my rails application , I uploaded files using `carrierwave` gem. When I am running my application and  using *local host* as `mongodb` database its retrieving the image perfectly but when I am trying to use `mongodb` as *remote system* like 192.168.X.XX its retriving only half of the url like **uploads/files/image.jpg** but this image is not displaying in my page. I used image_url to get the path.

Later I hardcoded to attach my ip 192.168.x.xx before that path . Like this http://192.168.x.xx:3000/uploads/files/image.jpg now its displaying the image. How should I display the image without hard coding?

Comment: Did you do rake assets:precompile ?

Comment: no. I didn't do anything like assets:precompile ...

Comment: Ok , you need to run this command rake assets:precompile in the application folder